JavaをVSCodeで実行できるが、Mac上だと実行できない
JavaのファイルをVSCodeのRunで実行すると実行できるが、Mac上だとコンパイルできても実行できない。
package Day4;

public class Fortune {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] color =
        {"黄色", "黄緑", "緑", "水色", "青",
            "紫", "ピンク", "赤", "オレンジ", "茶色"};

        System.out.print("あなたの運勢は");
        try {
            for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
                System.out.print(".");
                Thread.sleep(1000);  //1000ミリ秒停止
            }

            double fn1 = Math.random();  //0.0~1.0の乱数
            if( fn1 > 0.7) {
                System.out.println("大吉！");
            } else if (fn1 > 0.4) {
                System.out.println("中吉！");
            } else if (fn1 > 0.1) {
                System.out.println("小吉！");
            } else {
                System.out.println("凶");
            }

            int fn2 = ((int)(fn1 * 100) % 10);  //小数第２位の値
            System.out.println("ラッキーカラーは" + color[fn2]);

            System.out.println("fn1 =" + fn1);
            System.out.println("fn2 =" + fn2);

        }catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("割り込みが発生しました");
        }
    }
}

試したこと
以前実行できていたファイルと同じように一行目の package Day4; を消した状態でコンパイルし、実行できなかった。
Macのターミナル

VSCodeのRun起動後


パッケージが Day4 なら、java コマンドは一つ上の Desktop/java で実行する必要がありますね（コマンドは java Day4.Fortune）。package Day4 を消してコンパイルすれば Desktop/java/Day4 ディレクトリで実行可能なはずなので、他にも何か原因があるのかも知れませんが。

java コマンドの引数説明はこちらにあります:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/21/docs/specs/man/java.html

今回は以下の形式のものを用いることになります:

単一のソース・ファイル・プログラムを起動するには:
java [options] source-file [args ...]

source-file なので、ファイル名を指定します。つまり拡張子が必要です。
java Fortune.java


ちなみに、旧来からあるコンパイルしてから実行する方法は、クラスパスルート(~/Desktop/java)で:
javac Day4/Fortune.java # javacコマンドに指定するのはファイル名
java Day4.Fortune # javaコマンドに指定するのはクラス名(FQCN)

(javac コマンドの説明はこちら)
この場合の java コマンドは

クラス・ファイルを起動するには:
java [options] mainclass [args ...]

の形式です。
敢えて ~/Desktop/java/Day4 ディレクトリで行いたいのであれば明示的にクラスパスを指定する
javac Fortune.java
java -cp ../ Day4.Fortune

あるいは生成クラスの出力先を変更して現在のカレントパスをクラスパスルートになるようにする
javac -d . Fortune.java
java Day4.Fortune

ことなどで実行できます。

コメントありがとうございました！
丁寧に教えてくださり、誠にありがとうございます。
旧来の方法で行い、後半のものも行うことができました。
どちらが主流なのでしょうか。。。
お時間がある時で良いのでご教授お願いいたします。

一般的には javac Day4/Fortune.java; java Day4.Fortune で説明されていることが多いです。パッケージとディレクトリ構造(ファイルの位置)が一致しているので理解しやすいためだと思われます。(ただ、本格的なアプリケーション開発だとそもそも自分で javac コマンドを打つことはなく、 MavenやGradleといったビルドツールを用いることがほとんどで、ここで疑問に思われていることを意識する状況は無いと思ってもらって差し支えないです)

コメントの返信遅くなり、申し訳ございません。頭の片隅に留めておきたいと思います。分かりやすく丁寧な対応ありがとうございました。
